# displaying a vector in MATLAB using sprintf

Tags: matlab

I have a vector that looks like:

```
x = 
4.250000000000000
2.719000000000051
5.953000000000088
2.656999999999925
```

I want to create a string that looks like:

```
'4.25, 2.72, 5.95, 2.67'
```

Maybe, I can do something like

```
disp(sprintf('% 4.2f, % 4.2f, % 4.2f, % 4.2f,', x));
```

Is there a good way to write those four `% 4.2f` without actually writing four times so that it can match the length of `x`?

Comment: sprintf vectorizes by default.  You want disp(sprintf('%4.1f, ', x).  However, if you don't want the final comma, you'll need disp([sprintf('%4.2f, ', x(1:end-1)), sprintf('%4.2f', x(end))])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [dpwe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472891/displaying-a-vector-in-matlab-using-sprintf#comment37877578_24472891) `sprintf` support vectorization  by default thus

```
s = sprintf( '%.2f, ', x );
```

will result with

```
s =
   4.25, 2.72, 5.95, 2.66,
```

you can remove the trailing comma simply by

```
s=s(1:end-2)

s =
   4.25, 2.72, 5.95, 2.66
```